# How do I get rid of message.delete(); error message in dms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ok so basically I added `message.delete();` to all my commands on my bot, cause I want to delete the author's request for the command.

All is going fine, but when I DM the bot saying a command, as he can't delete the message, an error message will appear.

```
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\Pascale\Desktop\DungeonBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:32
(node:17772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
<node_internals>/internal/process/warning.js:32
(node:17772) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How do I make it so it justs returns and no error message appears??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. The first would be the bot ignoring you in DMs to avoid errors:

```js
// detects if the message is sent in dms, returns if so
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```

I suggest the first solution, although the second way would be to use a `try / catch` block:

```js
try {
 message.delete();
} catch {
 return;
}
```